# Is this relation an equivalence?

Tags: equivalence-relations

I'm completely lost in discrete mathematics. I have to find out whether $$xRy \iff \exists z\in \mathbb N \;\;[z\mid y \iff z\mid x]$$ where $x,y \in \mathbb N$ is an equivalence.

I know that relation must be reflexive, symmetric and transitive in order to be an equivalence.

If relation is reflexive, then $z\mid x \iff z\mid x$ must be the same, which is true. But I have no idea how to prove symmetry and transitivity of relation. Thanks for your advice

Comment: Should it be:$$xRy\iff\{ \forall z\in \mathbb{N}, z|x\iff z|y\}\quad ?$$

Comment: What exactly is meant by $z\in N:z|y$ & $  z|x$? Here $z$ is free and this is not a well defined relation in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Edited, I'm sorry for bad representation.

Comment: An equivalence relation on a set $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$ that has certain properties. What set $A$ are you dealing with? Also what is $N$ in your question?

Comment: Instead of saying "$z|x$ & $z|x$ must be the same", it's better to say "$z|x \iff z|x$" which is easier to understand.

Comment: Start by telling us something about $x$ and $y$. What are they? Integers maybe?

Comment: This is very hard to parse.  What if $z=1$?  Then (trusting that $x,y\in \mathbb N$) isn't your condition trivially satisfied?

Comment: Please, check my edit.

Comment: Wouldn't z = 1 make this true for all pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ and observe that $z:=\max(x,y)+1$ will **not** divide $x$ and will **not** divide $y$.

That means that the statement: $$z\mid x\iff z\mid y$$
is actually a **true** statement.

Proved is now that for **every** pair $\langle x,y\rangle\in\mathbb N^2$ we have $xRy$ (or equivalently $R=\mathbb N^2$).

Reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity are evident for this relation.

Comment: Thanks.
If I'm talking about equivalence classes, then for z = 1 there will be only 1 equivalence class (because 1 will divide $\allin z \in Z$) and for z > 1 there will be 2 equivalence classes (the number is dividable by z / is not dividable by z), am I right?

Comment: I meant $\forall z \in Z$

Comment: My answer deals with relation $\exists z\in\mathbb N[z|x\iff z|y]$ (the one stated in your question). In your comment you seem to ask questions about **other** relation(s): $z|x\iff z|y$ where $z$ is a **fixed** element of $\mathbb N$. Denoting such a relation by $R_z$ it can be observed that $R_z$ is an equivalence relation for every $z\in\mathbb N$. Secondly that $R_1$ has one equivalence class, and for $z\neq1$ the relation $R_z$ has indeed $2$ equivalence classes as you remark. Note that there is an essential difference between $R$ in your question and the relations $R_z$ mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

In plain english.  "Two natural numbers are related if they have a factor in common"  (which ... as $z$ *could* be $1$ means all numbers are related but ... I get ahead of myself.)

Reflexive:  Is is true that for all $x$ there is an $z$ so that $z|x \iff z|x$? well.... yeah.  $poo \iff poo$ is always true so... this is kind of trivial.

Symmetric: Is it true that if $z|x \iff z|y$ then $z|y \iff z|x$?  Well, yes... if $A \iff B$ then it's true $B \iff A$.

Transitive:  Suppose there is a $z$ so that $z|x \iff z|y$ and that there is a $w$ so the $w|y \iff w|u$.  Well.... foey.  I'm going to point out if $z = w =1$ we have $1|x$, $1|y$, and $1|u$ so all are always true so transitivity holds.

Comment: Transitivity even works on $\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: Yeah, I know but ... I didn't want to.